# Start QProcess on button press

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I'm building an application that launches an exe file on button press with `QProcess`. I have multiple buttons that are created in this way:

- Program reads from local database the information needed to create buttons (name, exe
  path)
- Then for each entry in the database it creates a button with the associated name in a
  previously created `QFrame`.

How can I associate the respective executable with the button?

Code

```
QSqlQueryModel query;
query.setQuery("SELECT * FROM games");
if (!query.record(0).isEmpty()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < query.rowCount(); i++) {
        QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(query.record(i).value("name").toString(), ui->frame);
        button->setGeometry(120 * (ui->frame->findChildren<QPushButton*>().size() - 1), 0, 110, 150);
        button->show();
    }
}
```

Notes: The number of buttons in the frame is random

System Info: I'm on Windows 11, using Qt 6.3.1 MSVC 64-bit

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html is something you should look at I think

Comment: ***How can I associate the respective executable with the button?*** Probably handle that in a slot that is connected to the buttons clicked signal. Or maybe a lambda connected to the clicked signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a lmbda like this:

```cpp
QSqlQueryModel query;
query.setQuery("SELECT * FROM games");
if (!query.record(0).isEmpty()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < query.rowCount(); i++) {
        QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(query.record(i).value("name").toString(), ui->frame);
        button->setGeometry(120 * (ui->frame->findChildren<QPushButton*>().size() - 1), 0, 110, 150);
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [=] {
          // Insert button specific code inside this lambda
        });
        button->show();
    }
}
```

From the docs: [Qt 6 Signals and Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html)